# Text Processing - Extracting Cleartext

Tags: bash, shell, hash, sha256

My script below simply hashes "Bob" with sha256sum. However, is it possible to reverse this process? So, basically using the output of the script to find the cleartext 'Bob'.

```
#!/bash/bash
echo -n Bob | sha256sum
```

I've looked around online about this but all the topics are about hashing strings and not the other way around. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question as I am new to scripting.

Comment: yep, it just encrypts it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sha256sum` is supposed to be a one-way hash.  If you could readily invert it, that would be proof that it was a failure.

`sha256sum` was designed to be a *cryptographic hash function* and, as [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function):

> The ideal cryptographic hash function has four main properties:
>
> - it is quick to compute the hash value for any given message
> - it is infeasible to generate a message from its hash value except by trying all possible messages
> - a small change to a message should change the hash value so extensively that the new hash value appears uncorrelated with the old
>     hash value
> - it is infeasible to find two different messages with the same hash value

So, no, there is no sensible way to invert it.

Comment: So the only way we get the cleartext would be to perform a dictionary attack or a trivial brute force attack? Thanks for replying.

Comment: Even with brute force and infinite computing resources, you won't be able to retrieve the original cleartext.There is an infinite number of cleartexts that maps to a given hash value. So, eventually the original cleartext will be in your set of candidate cleartexts with the desired hash, but you won't be able to tell if it was the one that has been hashed in the first palce.